# validation error messages are not shown in view in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

i'm using laravel 5.2 .. when submitting a form and check validation of data in **store** function and send back error data to the view, the error are not shown .
here is code for **userController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\user;
use Hash;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class userController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
    * Show the form for creating a new resource.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('user.usr_signup');
    }
    /**
    * Store a newly created resource in storage.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $firstName=input::get('firstName');
        $lastName=input::get('firstName');
        $password=Hash::make(input::get('pass'));
        $gender=input::get('gender');
        $mail=input::get('mail');
        $newUser= new user;
        $newUser->firstName=$firstName;
        $newUser->lastName=$lastName;
        $newUser->password=$password;
        $newUser->mail=$mail;
        $newUser->gender=$gender;

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
        'firstName' => 'required',
        'lastName' => 'required',
        'mail'=>'required|unique:user',
        'pass'=>'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->messages()) ;
        }
        else{
               $newUser->save();

        return redirect('homeController@index');
        }
    }
    /**
    * Display the specified resource.
    *
    * @param  int  $id
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
    * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
    *
    * @param  int  $id
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
    * Update the specified resource in storage.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  int  $id
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
    * Remove the specified resource from storage.
    *
    * @param  int  $id
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

and in the view **user.usr_signup.blade.php** here is the code to get error messages returned from validation

```
<form method="post" id="signUpForm" action="{{action('userController@store')}}">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6  col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstName" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="firstName">
              {{$errors->first('firstName')}}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6  col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lastName" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="lastName">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="user">email address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="user" name="mail" placeholder="email address">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender" class="sr-only">Gender</label>
            <select class="form-control input-lg input-block" id="gender" name="gender" size="1">
              <option value="1">male</option>
              <option value="2">female</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg input-block" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="sr-only">Reenter Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg input-block" id="reEnteredPass" name="rePass" placeholder="reenter password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" id="submitSignUpForm" name="submitSignUpFormButton">submit </button>
          </div>

        </form>
         @if (count($errors->all()) > 0)
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
              @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
              <li>{{ $error }}</li>
              @endforeach
            </ul>
          </div>
          @else
          @endif
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Change `return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->messages()) ;` to `return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator) ;`

Refer docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#other-validation-approaches)

Comment: Are you using the `web` middleware in routes.php?